# why not able to see new column for full name?

Tags: python, django, model

i am trying to concatinate strings of f_n and l_n, display as fullname column, display the fullname values character length, and display fullname length less than 12, display names as ascending order

```
from django.db import models

class c1(models.Model):
    f_n=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    l_n=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    des=models.TextField()


python manage.py shell

In [1]: from django.db.models.functions import Concat

In [2]: from django.db.models import Value as V

In [3]: from temp1app.models import c1


In [4]:             
result=c1.objects.annotate(fullname=Concat('f_n',V('('),'l_n',V(')')))

In [5]: result
Out[5]: <QuerySet [<c1: c1 object (1)>, <c1: c1 object (2)>, <c1: c1     
object (3)>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `__str__` representation method like the following:

```
from django.db import models

class c1(models.Model):
    f_n=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    l_n=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    des=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.f_n} {self.l_n}'
```

So in that way when you get a queryset like the following:

```
queryset = c1.objects.all()
```

If you print the `queryset`:

```
print(queryset)
```

You will be able to see the first name and last name.

If you really wanted to print the fullname property that you are creating with `annotate`, just do the following:

```
for i in result:
    i.fullname
```

Or you can do something like the following:

```
result.values_list('fullname', flat=True)
```

That will be like another property of your model.

Comment: for i in result:( what is result mean here). Thank you. could give example with annotate if required.

Comment: Is a variable that will take the iteration of each element that exists in result... example: `for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:` in this case `i` will take one element in the for loop. first `1` then `2` and so on.